# How to fix segfault in Python function "classify_argument" at ../src/x86/ffi64.c:158

Tags: python, c, segmentation-fault, gdb, swig

## Intro

I'm developing a program in python. It uses C library which is linked to python using SWIG.
C library is a some king of TCP server which processes client connections in separate C threads. These threads receive data from clients then do basic incoming data processing and parsing. After that the parsed data sent to python via "Python function callback". Result of that "Python function callback" then processed in C and sent back to client.

There were some segfaults which were caused by bugs in my code (double freeing memory, NULL pointer evaluation) which I have solved.

But now I have encountered a segfault in Python interpreter code. And I can't understand how to solve it.

## Debugging

I have got a backtrace using gdb (stack frames from 5 to 11 are omitted for clarity):

```
#0  classify_argument (type=0x55, classes=0x0, byte_offset=byte_offset@entry=0) at ../src/x86/ffi64.c:158
#1  0x00007ffff4b4212c in examine_argument (type=<optimized out>, classes=classes@entry=0x7fffeb522c60, in_return=in_return@entry=false, pngpr=pngpr@entry=0x7fffeb522c58, pnsse=pnsse@entry=0x7fffeb522c5c) at ../src/x86/ffi64.c:314
#2  0x00007ffff4b4296f in ffi_closure_unix64_inner (closure=0x7ffff7ff20f0, rvalue=0x7fffe4024820, reg_args=0x7fffeb522cc0, argp=0x7fffeb522d90 "") at ../src/x86/ffi64.c:615
#3  0x00007ffff4b42de4 in ffi_closure_unix64 () at ../src/x86/unix64.S:229
#4  0x00007ffff5fd0b21 in MyCCodeConnectionHandler (parameter=0x7ffff7ff20f0, connection=0x7fffe4024820, event=SERVER_CONNECTION_CLOSED) at my_code/server.c:586
...
#12 0x00007ffff7bc4184 in start_thread (arg=0x7fffeb523700) at pthread_create.c:312
#13 0x00007ffff71e403d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:111
```

When I try to print **type->type** variable in gdb I see:

```
(gdb) print type->type
Cannot access memory at address 0x5f
```

It seems that **type** argument of function **classify_argument** is invalid as I know addresses from 0x0000000000000000 to 0x000000000000FFFF are used for null pointer detection. And this is the cause of SegFault.

I have debugged other calls to function **classify_argument** using breakpoints and It showed me that **type** argument receives another kinds of values:

```
classify_argument (type=0x7ffff6662ee8, classes=0x1, byte_offset=byte_offset@entry=0) at ../src/x86/ffi64.c:158
classify_argument (type=0x7ffff65e7e10, classes=0x0, byte_offset=byte_offset@entry=0) at ../src/x86/ffi64.c:158
classify_argument (type=0x7ffff65e7e10, classes=0x0, byte_offset=byte_offset@entry=0) at ../src/x86/ffi64.c:158
```

and there were NO segfaults.

## Code and auxiliary information

Here is piece of ../src/x86/ffi64.c:

```
155 static size_t
156 classify_argument (ffi_type *type, enum x86_64_reg_class classes[],
157        size_t byte_offset)
158 {
159   switch (type->type)
160     {
161     case FFI_TYPE_UINT8:
162     case FFI_TYPE_SINT8:
163     case FFI_TYPE_UINT16:
164     case FFI_TYPE_SINT16:
165     case FFI_TYPE_UINT32:
166     case FFI_TYPE_SINT32:
167     case FFI_TYPE_UINT64:
168     case FFI_TYPE_SINT64:
169     case FFI_TYPE_POINTER:
170       {
171   size_t size = byte_offset + type->size;
172 
173   if (size <= 4)
174     {
175       classes[0] = X86_64_INTEGERSI_CLASS;
176       return 1;
177     }
178   else if (size <= 8)
179     {
180       classes[0] = X86_64_INTEGER_CLASS;
```

I know about GIL lock which is necessary to acquire before calling python code from C threads. Here is a piece of my_code/server.c

```
...
static void
MyCCodeConnectionHandler(void* parameter, ConnectionStruct *connection, ConnectionEvent event)
{
    if(parameter != NULL) { //parameter is a pointer to Python callback
        PyGILState_STATE gstate;
        gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();
        ((void (*)(long, long))parameter)((long)connection, event);
        PyGILState_Release(gstate);
    }
}
...
```

**paramter** argument has the following CTYPES definition in Python

```
ConnectionHandlerFuncType = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_long)
```

And converted using this Python code before passed to C

```
def py_callback(connection, event):
  # some code here

ctype_function_wrapper = ConnectionHandlerFuncType(py_callback)
cfunction_pointer = ctypes.cast(ctype_function_wrapper, ctypes.c_void_p).value
# cfunction_pointer is passed as parameter arg to MyCCodeConnectionHandler
```

Please help me to solve this segfault.

Comment: What does `my_code/server.c` calling into Python look like? Are you acquiring the GIL before calling into Python?

Comment: @EmployedRussian I have updated the question. Yes I acquire GIL lock before calling python

Comment: You tried valgrinding it, in case it's a buffer overrun or some other type of memory corruption going on elsewhere?  These sorts of things can be very hard to pin down just from the symptoms.

Comment: @NPE thanks. I will try kind of check you mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Directors](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Python_directors) have solved my issue. It seem that this is the only right way to make callbacks in SWIG. My way of passing callback to C level was wrong.

Here is how my C callback look now:

```
static void
MyCCodeConnectionHandler(void* parameter, ConnectionStruct *connection, ConnectionEvent event)
{
    //parameter contains (ConnectionCallbackDirector *) value casted to (void *)
    if(parameter != NULL) {
        PyGILState_STATE gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();
        ((ConnectionCallbackDirector *)parameter)->run(connection, event);
        PyGILState_Release(gstate);
    }
}
```

Director's code:

```
class ConnectionCallbackDirector {
  public:
    virtual ~ConnectionCallbackDirector() {}
    virtual void run(ConnectionStruct *, ConnectionEvent) {}
};
```

Both of them I have placed at the SWIG's *.i file and `enabled director feature for SWIG module and ConnectionCallbackDirector class`.

In python I have wrote this class inherited from ConnectionCallbackDirector

```
class ConnectionCallback(my_c_lib.ConnectionCallbackDirector):

  def __init__(self, pycallback):
    my_c_lib.ConnectionCallbackDirector.__init__(self)
    self._pycallback = pycallback

  def run(self, connection, event):
    return self._pycallback(connection, event)
```

And passed an object created from ConnectionCallback class into the C code.

Now everything is fine!